# What is the measure of the $ \angle BDC$ in the trapeze, rectangle below?

Tags: geometry

For reference:
What is the measure of the $\angle BDC$ in the trapeze, rectangle below, straight in $A$ and $B$. In A and B we trace $CH \perp BD~(H ~in~ BD)$. If $\angle BCH = 2\angle BDC$ and 3AD = 8CH, calculate $\angle BDC$

[image]

My progress:

$\triangle AEB \sim \triangle CHD\\
BE = CD\\
BE ~is~ bissector\\
\frac{x}{AB}=\frac{5x}{3BD}\implies AB = \frac{3BD}{5}$

[image]

but it wasn't enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You drew the right diagram but you just made a mistake by writing $BC$ instead of $BD$ in your working.

Using your diagram, as $BE$ is angle bisector of $\angle ABD$,

$\cfrac{BD}{AB} = \cfrac{5x/3}{x} = \cfrac{5}{3}$

By Pythagoras in $\triangle ABD$,

$AB^2 + \left(\cfrac{8x}{3}\right)^2 = \left(\cfrac{5 AB}{3}\right)^2 \implies AB = 2x$

Then $\tan \alpha = \cfrac{AE}{AB} = \cfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: ..grateful for the alert and for the help..I've corrected it